# encounter XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException when start java web application

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I try to learn springmvc.And now I encounter a problem.

There is an exception which called `XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException` when I start my web application.

Here are my files.

1.hello-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!--指明 controller 所在包，并扫描其中的注解-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="cn.qingtianr"/>

     <!--静态资源(js、image等)的访问 -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <!-- 开启注解 -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!--ViewResolver 视图解析器-->
    <!--用于支持Servlet、JSP视图解析-->
    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

2.web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

3.pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cn.qingtianr</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringVmex</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringVmex Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-data.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringVmex</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

The exception is

```
11:06:59.288 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 24 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hello-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 20; cos-all-limited.1.2: An ''all'' model group must appear in a particle with '{'min occurs'}'='{'max occurs'}'=1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the '{'content type'}' of a complex type definition.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:632) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:680) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:551) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cos-all-limited.1.2: An ''all'' model group must appear in a particle with '{'min occurs'}'='{'max occurs'}'=1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the '{'content type'}' of a complex type definition.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:267) ~[xercesImpl-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:201) ~[xercesImpl-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

I try to search in stackoverflow.And find some question which is like this exception.And the answer is to change my `<beans ....` , but it doesn't work.

So can anyone help me?thx.

EDIT:

I change `commons-dbcp` version from `1.4` to `1.3`.And the exception is disapper.

So I want to know why?

I spent pretty of time to find the reason and I still don't know about this problem.

Comment: can you post your full stack of exception?

Comment: ok,now I add it.@subburoyal

Comment: add this `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"` schema in`<beans..>` tag in your `hello-servlet.xml`

Comment: I add it.But is doesn't work.It is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Boot then use Spring Boot. Fix your dependencies. Remove the version numbers and let Spring Boot manage your dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As you are using Spring Boot I expect you also have a class extending `SpringBootServletInitializer`. If so your xml configuration does nothing as well as your web.xml. You should remove those.

Also you could remove `commons-dbcp` as the spring boot web dependency includes tomcat-jdbc as a pool (which is at least better compared to commons-dbcp however I would recommend the HikariCP instead of either).